# Format multiple cells in a row (e.g. B1 to H1) when they are greater than a value indicated in a cell (e.g. A1)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, excel-2013

I need a formula that will allow me to set conditional formatting in Excel 2013 so that it automatically formats multiple cells in a row that are greater than a value in the first column of that row.  For example, to format cells in `B2` to `F2` if they are greater than the value in `A2`.  The same goes for the next row etc. etc.

Any ideas of how I can do this using conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Please try a CF formula rule of:

```
=B1>$A1
```

with Applies to:

```
=$B$1:$H$100
```

or adjust the range to suit.